# MySQL alternative to nested queries?

Tags: mysql, nested

I have read that using nested queries is not a good idea, It was said that nested queries slow down mysql a great lot and stuff like that, so I figured I should not use nested queries, but what is really an alternative to that?

For example I have a comments rating system which helps bring top-rated comments to the top and it goes in 2 tables:

`comments` which stores comments
`comment_ratings` which stores the comment `ID` and the person who has rated it.

**Note**: there's only positive ratings so if a record exists in the `comment_ratings` table its +1.

So now if I wanted to pick up comments for some stuff I'd go like

```
SELECT stuff, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_ratings s WHERE s.id = c.id) as votes
FROM comments c
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

How would I do this without using a nested query?

Comment: Two answers to give you the basic idea. Note sometimes the DBMS will optimise a sub-query as a join anyway. Using joins properly is a good habit though and personally I go that way first and then may be rework if it will optimise better. As a rule I find subqueries for columns less readable than a join, but that's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether nested queries are good or bad depends on the situation.  In your particular example, if you have an index on `comment_ratings(id)`, then there is probably no issue.  Maybe that should be `comment_ratings(comment_id)` -- the naming convention is poor for these tables.

You could replace this with an aggregation query:

```
select c.*, count(cr.id) as votes
from comments c left join
     comment_ratings cr
     on c.id = cr.id
group by c.id
order by votes desc;
```

However, because of the way that MySQL implements `group by`, this might perform worse than your original query.  I *prefer* the `group by`.  To me, it more clearly describes what you want and most other database engines will optimize it well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select stuff, count(*) as votes
from comments c, comment_ratings cr
where c.id = cr.id
group by stuff
order by votes desc;
```

and as gordon mentioned, to not forget the comments with no rating.. go for left join:

```
select stuff, count(cr.id) as votes
from comments c left join 
     comment_ratings cr on c.id = cr.id
group by stuff
order by votes desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79e54/2

Comment: This is not equivalent.  It will filter out comments that have no ratings.

Comment: of course, I was a bit lazy to write a left join ;) good point! ;) I have added that one too, in my answer! thx